# Azure function - should context.done be called after each loop or at end

Tags: azure, azure-functions

In an Azure function say I have:

```
const cosmosDBTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (context: Context, documents: any[]): Promise<void> {
    if (!!documents && documents.length > 0) {
        documents.forEach(function (document) {
            context.bindings.outputdocuments = document
            //1 - SHOULD IT GO HERE
        }); 
    }
//2 - SHOULD IT GO HERE
}
```

Is the correct place to place `context.done` be in position 1 or 2. Namely should be after each document in the loop at the very end?

Thanks.

Comment: forEach is not async so if you call it in 1 place then it will call done on first item, also if documents are empty it wont be called at all . So should go to 2

Comment: Right. So I placed it position 2 and it only outputted the second document, not the first. I guess I need to use some await code?

Comment: Does it work now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure how its done in node js but I assume should be something like this

```
const cosmosDBTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (context: Context, documents: any[]): Promise<void> {
    if (!!documents && documents.length > 0) {
        context.bindings.outputdocuments = documents; 
    }
    context.done();
}
```

Reason you have only last document written is that if you do

```
context.bindings.outputdocuments = document
```

It means that you overriding output by last document via loop instead of providing an array.

Comment: Ok. That works. So I guess I had to remove the loop as it wasn't required.