# Azure Function - After Out binding how to trigger a function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function. I've created an out binding and data is being written to that output CosmosDB.

However I want to ask, once that has done, is it possible to hit another trigger?

Or do i have to manually write code to add to the DB, namely not using the out binding?

Thanks.

Heres the code:

The function.json

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "cosmosDBTrigger",
      "name": "documents",
      "direction": "in",
      "leaseCollectionName": "leases",
      "connectionStringSetting": "COSMOSDB_INPUT_CONNECTION_STRING",
      "databaseName": "default",
      "collectionName": "metadata",
      "createLeaseCollectionIfNotExists": false,
      "leaseCollectionPrefix": "IngestMetadata",
      "startFromBeginning": true
    },
    {
      "type": "cosmosDB",
      "name": "outputdocuments",
      "direction": "out",
      "connectionStringSetting": "COSMOSDB_CONNECTION_STRING",
      "databaseName": "default",
      "collectionName": "metadata",
      "createIfNotExists": true
  }
  ],
  "scriptFile": "../dist/IngestMetadata/index.js"
}
```

And teh code itself:

```
const cosmosDBTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (context: Context, documents: any[]): Promise<void> {
    if (!!documents && documents.length > 0) {
        context.bindings.outputdocuments = documents;
    }

    context.done();
}
```

So after the `context.done` I want to hit another trigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use azure [function triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2#trigger---javascript-example) for that

**function.json**

```
{
    "type": "cosmosDBTrigger",
    "name": "documents",
    "direction": "in",
    "leaseCollectionName": "leases",
    "connectionStringSetting": "<connection-app-setting>",
    "databaseName": "Tasks",
    "collectionName": "Items",
    "createLeaseCollectionIfNotExists": true
}
```

then js code.

```
  module.exports = function (context, documents) {
      context.log('First document Id modified : ', documents[0].id);

      context.done();
    }
```

So you could have logic for instance from http trigger you write to cosmos db, and another trigger as soon as anything is written to cosmos db and so on

PS. So to sum up, since I answered your previous question as a result you will have 2 functions, first is from your other question where you write output to cosmos db and second function from this question where it will be triggered as soon as 1 function will finish execution and data available in cosmos db

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55644026/azure-function-should-context-done-be-called-after-each-loop-or-at-end/55644161#55644161
So Volodymyr - its bascailly after the context.done in this question. I want to send a trigger.

Comment: Do I need to do somehting like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-manually-run-non-http

Comment: No. Link you posted is kind of how to test your queue/cosmosdb triggers without actually writing to cosmosdb or queue.

Comment: So basically back to your first question as a result you will have 2 azure functions, one from your first question which will write to cosmosdb and second from current question where you will trigger as soon as 1 function is complete

Comment: @userMod2 I've answered to it :)

Comment: Ah I see - so basically there will be 2 fucntions?

Comment: @userMod2 yep. This is right way to go since you want you function to execute as fast as possible, plus you could have multiple ways to write to cosmos db

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191698/discussion-between-usermod2-and-volodymyr-bilyachat).